# My scrapy can't get valid response

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

When i use scrapy to get some stocks information from 'http://quote.eastmoney.com/stocklist.html',I can't get right response. Actually, I get nothing when I run it.
Here is the contents of stocks.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re

class StocksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "stocks"

start_urls = ['http://quote.eastmoney.com/stocklist.html']

def parse(self, response):


    for i in Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="quotesearch"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract():
        try:
            stock=re.split(r'[./]',i)[5]

            url='https://gupiao.baidu.com/stock/'+stock+'.html'
            yield scrapy.Rquest(url,callback=self.parse_stock)
        except:
            continue

def parse_stock(self,response):
    infoDict={}


    name=Selector(response).xpath('//a[@class="bets-name"]/text()').extract()[0]
    keylist=Selector(response).xpath('//dl/dt/text()').extract()

    for i in range(len(keylist)):
        try:
            val=Selector(response).xpath('//dl/dd/text()').extract()[0]
        except:
            val='--'
        infoDict[keylist[i]]=val
    infoDict.update({'股票名称':name[0].split()[0]+'('+Selector(response).xpath('//a[@class="bets-name"]/span/text()')[0].extract()[0]+')'})


    yield infoDict
```

Here is what I get when I run it:

```
2017-06-05 20:28:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: BaiduStocks)
    2017-06-05 20:28:32 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'BaiduStocks', 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'BaiduStocks.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['BaiduStocks.spiders']}
2017-06-05 20:28:32 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['BaiduStocks.pipelines.BaidustocksInfoPipeline']
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quote.eastmoney.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quote.eastmoney.com/stocklist.html> (referer: None)
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 458,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 570201,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 12, 28, 33, 930937),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 12, 28, 33, 28477)}
2017-06-05 20:28:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have been working on it for a few days, but I can't tell what's wrong. So I really need your help.
Thank you all!

Comment: Looking at your logs it seems like `parse()` is not generating any follow up. Do you by any chance have `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` set to `True` in your `settings.py`? Try removing that line.

Comment: I have tried to remove that line, but I still meet the same situation.   So sad-_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I did a short code review:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re


class StocksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stocks"

    start_urls = ['http://quote.eastmoney.com/stocklist.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        # response has a shortcut for selector
        for i in response.xpath('//div[@id="quotesearch"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract():
            # never silently catch and drop errors
            stock = re.split(r'[./]', i)[5]
            url = 'https://gupiao.baidu.com/stock/' + stock + '.html'
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_stock)

    def parse_stock(self, response):
        # objects should be lowercase in python
        item = dict()
        # there's extract_first shortcut for extract()[0]
        name = response.xpath('//a[@class="bets-name"]/text()').extract_first('')
        keylist = response.xpath('//dl/dt/text()').extract()

        # for each is preferred loop style.
        for key in keylist:
            # extract_first allows a default argument to be set
            item[key] = response.xpath('//dl/dd/text()').extract_first('--')
        data = Selector(response).xpath('//a[@class="bets-name"]/span/text()').extract_first('') + ')'
        item['data'] = '{}({})'.format(name.split()[0], data)
        yield item
```

Aside from minor issues the biggest one was that your `try/except` clause in `parse()` method just quit silenty and you had a typo `Rquest`, so the spider just went on - you should never have silent blanket exceptions for this very reason :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You are so nice! But I still don't understand what happened to the 'try except'.**When I use code like below, things will be right. **But I can't tell the difference between this and mine.Thank you again!'    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)').extract():
            try:
                stock = re.findall(r"[s][hz]\d{6}", href)[0]
                url = 'https://gupiao.baidu.com/stock/' + stock + '.html'
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_stock)
            except:
                continue'

Comment: @L.Jack Your original code would break on this line `yield scrapy.Rquest(url,callback=self.parse_stock)`. Here Request is misspelled thus python raises `AttributeError` and since you catch _all_ errors silently you never know why and when and for what reason something happened.